# Jquery Validation Rule Depends Generates Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

When I try to use jQuery validation rules depends as follows:

```
<script>
$('#sign-up-form form').validate({
    rules: {
        state: "required",
        school: {
            depends: function(element) {
                return $("#id_school_id").val().length;
                }
            }
    }
});
</script>
```

Each time the depends part of the rule runs I get 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined`

The id that I'm checking is there (#id_school_id).
I'm using jquery.validation.js v 1.11.1

Comment: Nothing to do with `depends`, but I recommend updating to version 1.13.1 since a few bugs have been fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I misunderstood depends to be a rule method. You need to apply its value to a rule method. So, for example

```
$('#sign-up-form form').validate({
rules: {
    state: "required",
    school: {
        required: {
            depends: function(element) {
                return $("#id_school_id").val().length;
            }
        }
    }
},
messages: {
    school: "Please choose a valid school name from the choices presented"
}
});

</script>
```

Whether the field 'school' is required depends on the field 'school_id' having a length.